# Ubuntu 20.04 screen Freeze but still can move cursor and hear/send mic voice (from zoom)

Tags: 20.04

I can ssh to the machine, replace window manager `mutter --replace` but nothing happened, screen still frozen, can move cursor; I don't want to restart since I don't want to lose the zoom pc and kazam recording. what commands should I run without restarting?

no error on journalctl

no error on dmesg